# Insufficient system resources to complete the requested service

Tags: c, dev-c++

Recently, on [Dev C++](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html), I was trying to compile some of my programs for school.

Unfortunately, I got an error:

```
Insufficient system resources to complete the requested service
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You mentioned that you have enough ram, how about other ulimit's? Max number of open file descriptors? How large of a project are you trying to run / compile?

Comment: Since this isn't a problem with your code it's better addressed to [Super User](http://superuser.com). What's the motivation behind using Dev C++? Visual Studio Express is is usually a better call in nearly every situation.

Comment: Mate before that problem existed there was an Avira notification telling me that my code was a virus, well i think that's very normal. But come on im trying to run a hello world file xD

Comment: Migrate to [su]?

Comment: Migrate to [su]?

Answer (score 1):

**You are probably out of RAM.**

Kill programs you're not using to clear some up.

Comment: Well, i have a 3GB ram, not the best thing but still even if i have everything closed it still wont let me run my compiled file..

Comment: Well, at any rate, this is probably the more common solution to the problem, if not yours.