# if passed an array as pointer to a function I get "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service"

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Im trying the following function

```
vector<int> getsmallest(int* arr, int size, int lessthan) 
{
    vector<int> v;
    v.clear();
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < lessthan)
        {
            v.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

above function gives me error

> Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

where as if I change the arguments as below

```
vector<int> getsmallest(int arr[], int size, int lessthan)
```

works fine.

function call is as follows

```
int arr1[] = { 10, 5, 30, 40, 20 };
    vector<int> v = getsmallest(arr1, 5, 25);
```

what is the difference here?

Comment: please show a [mre], you likely have undefined behaviour somewhere

Comment: What exactly is giving the error message? Is it the Visual C++ runtime (I don't know anything else that gives C++ error messages at runtime)? How and where are you calling the function?

Comment: yes, while runtime I'm getting this error, I'm calling the function in main

Comment: @Nayak We need to see a full example.  We have no idea where `arr` comes from, how or where it is initialized with data, or whether `size` is valid, etc.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between `vector<int> getsmallest(int* arr, int size, int lessthan)` and `vector<int> getsmallest(int arr[], int size, int lessthan)`; these are two equivalent ways to write the same declaration. To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie elsewhere. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: @Nayak *Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service* -- Are you using one of those "online compiler" websites?

Comment: I'd really suggest you use `std::array` or `std::vector` in the future after this. The C++ STL is a very useful tool and you should definitely use it when possible. `std::vector` and `std::array` would save you from having to suffer a lot of the undefined behavior of C style arrays.

Comment: *Kindly let me know what is the difference here* -- There is no difference.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `v.clear()` is not needed. A default-initialized vector will start out empty.

Comment: "Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service" is a Windows driver error. There is absolutely no difference whatsoever between `int arr[]` and `int *arr` function arguments.

Comment: [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) will do most of the work for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48212683/insufficient-system-resources-to-complete-the-requested-service

Comment: `ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES` usually means too big a buffer or out of nonpaged memory or some other degenerate atrocity.